# ios : same ui controls across various screens in ios app

Tags: ios5, uibutton

I am fairly new to iOS development. My requirement is I am designing an app that contains 5 screens . I have a set of  UI controls( 1 UIImageView 5 UIButtons acting like tab bars for each screen) that are common for all the screens. When a button is clicked only the bottom half of the view needs to change with a relevant details while the buttons stay intact(similar to tab control in windows).

Is there a way to achieve this design? Can I share UI controls across multiple screens without repetition in code or 
 Is there a way to change only the bottom half of the screen when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate class that would create your UIControls and then for each viewcontroller you call the appropiate method to get the UIControls you want.

```
@interface UIControlMaker : NSObject{

    id controlmakerDelegate; // This is so that you can send messages to the viewcontrollers 
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) id controlmakerDelegate; // Release it in dealloc method

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate;
- (UIView *)createCommonUIControls;
```

In the implementation file

```
@implementation UIControlMaker

@synthesize controlmakerDelegate;

- (id)initWithDelegate:(id)delegate{

    if(self = [super init]){
        [self setControlMakerDelegate:delegate];
        return self;
    }else
        return nil;
}

- (UIView *)createCommonUIControls{

      UIView *uicontrolsHolder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,40,320,50)];

      // Create as many uicontrols as you want. It'd be better if you have a separate class to create them

     // Let's create a button for the menuItem
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 , 0, 50, 35)];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button setTitle:@"Button 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:controlmakerDelegate action:@selector(buttonOnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      [uicontrolsHolder addView:button];
      [button release];

      // Add more uicontrols here

      retun [uicontrolsHolder autorelease];
}
```

Then in your viewcontrollers create an instance of UIControlMaker and call the createCommonUIControls method which will return a View that you can add to your viewcontroller. Hope that was clear.